# Appropriate tag for locally-hosted webapp / web interface?

Tags: discussion, tags

I previously tagged [my question about locally-hosted web interfaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400935/how-can-i-manage-multiple-end-user-style-localhost-applications) with `localhost` (since that's what you'd use to access them), but that tag was removed.

I think that although uncommon, this interface is *enough* of a phenomenon that it justifies tagging in some way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would rather prefer to use a more appropriated tag like [webserver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/webserver), which means exactly what you are looking for:

> A web server is a program that responds to network requests over the HTTP or HTTPS protocol.

In fact, locally hosted applications can be shared using other interfaces but the local interface. The interface they are being hosted into isn't differentiating enough to make a useful tag. If that was the case, most MySQL, Postgres, services in general, should be tagged like that.